# Arrays as parameters in Axis2 POJO Webservices?

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, pojo

I'm a Axis2 / Webservice newbie and I'm trying to turn a simple POJO into a webservice (code below). The class `PieceInfo` is annotated with `@XmlRootElement` and I have a class `ObjectFactory` which returns a PieceInfo in a method (code below). Methods using `PieceInfo` work, methods using `List<PieceInfo>` or `PieceInfo[]` as parameters throw JAXB exceptions such as `java.util.List is not known to this context`. I thought List or array should just work fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
@WebService (name="KMPService",targetNamespace="http://www.ict.ie.tss/")
@MTOM
public interface KMPServiceInterface {

@WebMethod
void updateRootInfo(String username, String password, PieceInfo info);

@WebMethod
PieceInfo getRootInfo(String username, String password);

@WebMethod
void put(String username, String password, List<PieceInfo> infoList);

@WebMethod
PieceInfo[] get(String username, String password,
    PieceInfo[] infoList);

@WebMethod
void deleteEntries(String username, String password,
    PieceInfo[] infoList);

}
```

ObjectFacotry:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

public PieceInfo createPieceInfo(){
    return new PieceInfo();
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the answer is: **Don't use Axis2**. Using cxf now snd everything works with Lists and Arrays out of the box.

Comment: Do you have official doc reference for this Axis2 limitation? In my company, I need to support project on Websphere application server and Im facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays instead of java.util.List.

Remember that Web Services are supposed to inter-op with everything, like .Net web service clients who would have no idea how to build a java.util.List object, but should be able to figure out how to build an array of PieceInfo objects.

Hopefully that removes your "not known to this context" problems. Also make sure that PieceInfo has a zero argument constructor so that the Axis framework can create one.

Comment: Array doesn't work either. If I use array I get: `[...model.PieceInfo; is not known to this context]`. If I just use a single `PieceInfo` object, it works fine. Just not Arrays of them or Lists of them.